# simprof, Error in if (denom != 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, missing-data, similarity

I would like to test the pairwise similarity between 22 study sites (rows) using the **simprof** function in the 'clustsig' package in R.

It is based on Clarke, Somerfield, and Gorley (2008), who developed SIMPROF, a “similarity profile,” which represents the matrix of pairwise similarity values between any set of objects. The data represent percent cover of benthic organisms on a coral reef with each row summing to 100.

Using a matrix with more than 20 rows, I get the following error,
"Error in if (denom != 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

I do not get this error with 20 rows or less.

Any guidance or possible explanation for this error would be appreciated.

```
install.packages("clustsig")
```

```
require(clustsig)
```

```
mdat2 <- matrix(
  c(2.0, 3.0, 32.3, 0.0, 2.3, 43.7, 0.3, 0.3, 2.0, 0.0, 13.7, 0.3,   #1
    16.9, 0.0, 4.5, 0.0, 12.4, 36.9, 0.0, 0.7, 0.7, 5.9, 21.0, 1.0,  #2
    28.3, 0.0, 7.3, 0.0, 21.7, 12.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7, 4.2, 21.7, 3.1,  #3
    4.1, 2.0, 31.8, 0.0, 6.1, 31.1, 3.0, 0.7, 5.7, 0.3, 15.2, 0.0,   #4 
    13.1, 0.7, 46.3, 0.3, 0.0, 1.7, 0.3, 0.0, 0.3, 0.3, 36.9, 0.0,   #5
    1.3, 23.7, 55.5, 9.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.4, 0.3,    #6
    4.1, 0.7, 27.9, 0.7, 3.1, 32.1, 14.5, 0.0, 4.8, 0.0, 11.0, 1.0,  #7
    1.0, 4.7, 68.9, 0.0, 1.0, 11.8, 3.4, 0.3, 2.4, 0.0, 6.1, 0.3,    #8
    8.2, 0.0, 49.1, 0.0, 0.7, 5.5, 0.0, 0.3, 0.3, 0.0, 32.3, 3.4,    #9
    17.8, 2.4, 48.8, 0.0, 0.3, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 11.1, 0.0, 13.8, 0.7,  #10
    17.3, 0.4, 30.0, 5.1, 0.0, 18.1, 0.0, 1.1, 5.8, 0.0, 21.7, 0.7,  #11
    8.1, 1.0, 62.3, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7, 0.0, 19.2, 1.7,    #12
    12.8, 0.0, 65.9, 0.3, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7, 0.0, 17.9, 1.4,   #13
    16.3, 4.2, 46.7, 0.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 31.5, 0.7,   #14
    24.9, 0.0, 15.4, 0.0, 0.3, 2.0, 0.3, 0.7 ,2.7, 0.0, 50.9, 2.7,   #15
    19.8, 0.0, 35.1, 0.0, 0.0, 2.1, 1.4, 0.7, 1.4, 0.0, 39.2, 0.3,   #16
    14.2, 0.0, 48.1, 0.0, 0.3, 11.2, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 24.1,  1.0, #17
    25.0, 0.7, 27.4, 0.3, 0.7, 28.0, 0.0, 1.0, 6.1, 0.0, 10.1, 0.7,  #18
    7.4, 0.3, 41.1, 0.0, 0.0, 27.4, 0.3, 0.3, 10.7, 0.0, 11.7, 0.7,  #19
    8.7, 5.4, 63.4, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.3, 0.0, 17.8, 0.3,    #20
    15.9, 0.0, 34.2, 0.0, 2.7, 6.4, 0.3, 1.7, 2.7, 0.0, 34.2, 1.7,   #21
    5.1, 1.7, 60.3, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 25.9, 0.0     #22
  ), 

  nrow = 22, ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE,

  dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2", "row3", "row4", "row5", 
                    "row6", "row7", "row8", "row9", "row10",
                    "row11", "row12", "row13", "row14", "row15",
                    "row16", "row17", "row18", "row19", 
                    "row20", "row21", "row22"
  ),

  c("c.1", "c.2", "c.3", "c.4", "c.5", "c.6",
    "c.7", "c.8", "c.9", "c.10", "c.11", "c.12")
  )
)
```

```
mdat2.simprof <- simprof(mdat2, 
                         num.expected = 1000, num.simulated = 999,
                         method.distance = "actual-braycurtis",
                         method.transform = "identity", alpha = 0.05,
                         sample.orientation = "row", const = 1,
                         silent = FALSE, increment = 100, 
                         undef.zero = TRUE, warn.braycurtis = TRUE)
```

Comment: I can't explain why,  but I suspect the high number of zeros in your data may be causing trouble. I say this only because while playing around with your data, I tried adding 1 to each data value, and the code ran to completion. So maybe some kind of transformation is needed?

Comment: xilliam - Thank you for the suggestion. I will research appropriate transformations and proceed.